# Error trying to use a foreach loop with a sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nerddinner

I am recreating the website [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.com/) using MVC, ASP.NET. I have created a database containing the dinners, their dates, and other related information. On my index View, I am attempting to use a foreach loop to list all the dinners to the screen. I keep getting the error:

> "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Dinner'
>   because 'Dinner' does not contain a public definition for
>   'GetEnumerator'"

```
    <ul>
    @foreach (var dinner in Model) 
    {

        <li>                 
            @dinner.Title           
            on 
            @dinner.EventDate.ToShortDateString()
            at
            @dinner.EventDate.ToShortTimeString()
        </li>
    }                    
    </ul>
```

I am pretty new to this and am not sure how to correct this issue, or really even WHERE the issue is located.

Here is my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Justin-Mikesell/NerdDinner) for the project. Sorry if the question is ambiguous, I am just a little lost and not really sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code snippet so people here can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is of the Type `@model NerdDinner.Models.Dinner`

So basically your Model is not a list. Changing your model to  `@model IEnumerable<NerdDinner.Models.Dinner>` or `@model List<NerdDinner.Models.Dinner>` should fix your issue

edit: change Index.cshtml to

```
@model List<NerdDinner.Models.Dinner>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Upcoming Dinners</h2>

<ul>

@foreach(var dinner in Model)
{
    <li>
        @dinner.Title
        on
        @dinner.EventDate.ToShortDateString()
        at
        @dinner.EventDate.ToShortDateString()
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, now this is where my genius is going to show. (sarcasm) So I figured something like this was the issue, but where do I make this change at?

Comment: And don't worry, we all have been there, after a few years in programming now I still make mistakes that seems fairly simple

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach(var dinner in Model.dinners)
{
    <li>
        @dinner.Title
        on
        @dinner.EventDate.ToShortDateString()
        at
        @dinner.EventDate.ToShortDateString()
    </li>
}
```

Try this, you have to define which model you want to loop

Comment: If I would only have one item to show I wouldn't opt for a Model per se, just loop trough that item, but this works too

Comment: Yes, thats true

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but unfortunately does not fix it. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, the model needs to be an `IEnumerable`like:

```
@model IEnumerable<NerdDinner.Models.Dinners>
```

and then you can use the `foreach`as below:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
```

//your code goes here..

```
}
```

Hope this helps.